# separate value in columns with condition in bash

Tags: bash, awk, grep, conditional-statements

I got a txt file like below

```
008 750 16.3763  1
028 572 -91.1915  2
031 421 -19.2564  1
113 265 -5.05956  1
147 099 38.017  1
154 161 -4.43984  1
170 101 28.2171  1
179 728 -31.2691  2
```

and I would like to separate the third column based on the value in fourth column:
if the fourth column is 1, then insert another two column as "(value of third column) NA", if 2, make it "NA (value of third column)", then delete the third and fourth column. I will get

```
008 750 16.3763    NA
028 572 NA        -91.1915  
031 421 -19.2564   NA
113 265 -5.05956   NA
147 099 38.017     NA
154 161 -4.43984   NA
170 101 28.2171    NA
179 728 NA        -31.2691
```

### Could anyone tell me how to achieve this in a bash command?

I thought a quick way of this is to replace the fourth column with NA if the value is 1. if it is 2, switch the third and fourth column and then replace the 2 with NA.

```
awk '{OFS="\t";if($i==1) $i="NA"; print}' *.txt
```

But I don't know how can I switch values of two column.

Thanks! :)

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Stackoverflow works best if you show that you have made an effort, show the code that you developed (however primitive), and describe the problems that the code is giving you.

Comment: I thought a quick way of this is to replace the fourth column with NA if the value is 1. if it is 2, switch the third and fourth column and then replace the 2 with NA.

Answer (score 0):

> *"replace the fourth column with NA if the value is 1. if it is 2,
>   switch the third and fourth column and then replace the 2 with NA"*

Try this:

```
$ awk '$4==1{$4="NA"} $4==2{$4=$3; $3="NA"} 1' OFS='\t' 1.txt
008     750     16.3763 NA
028     572     NA      -91.1915
031     421     -19.2564        NA
113     265     -5.05956        NA
147     099     38.017  NA
154     161     -4.43984        NA
170     101     28.2171 NA
179     728     NA      -31.2691
```

#### How it works

- `$4==1{$4="NA"}`

  If the fourth column is `1`, then we set it to `NA`.
- `$4==2{$4=$3; $3="NA"}`

  If the fourth column is `2`, then we make the fourth column equal to the third column and then replace the third column with `NA`.
- `1`

  This is awk's cryptic shorthand for print-the-line.  If you don't like cryptic, you could use `{print}` instead.
- `OFS='\t'`

  This sets the field separator on output to a tab.

If the field separator on input is a tab, then you may want to specify that also:

```
awk -F'\t' '$4==1{$4="NA"} $4==2{$4=$3; $3="NA"} 1' OFS='\t' 1.txt
```

#### Improved formatting

The above uses tab as the field separator and that means that the columns do not allows line up nicely.  To fix that, we can use `column -t`:

```
$ awk '$4==1{$4="NA"} $4==2{$4=$3; $3="NA"} 1' OFS='\t' 1.txt | column -t
008  750  16.3763   NA
028  572  NA        -91.1915
031  421  -19.2564  NA
113  265  -5.05956  NA
147  099  38.017    NA
154  161  -4.43984  NA
170  101  28.2171   NA
179  728  NA        -31.2691
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '{ if ($4==1) {$4="NA"} else {$4=$3; $3="NA"} }1' file | column -t
008  750  16.3763   NA
028  572  NA        -91.1915
031  421  -19.2564  NA
113  265  -5.05956  NA
147  099  38.017    NA
154  161  -4.43984  NA
170  101  28.2171   NA
179  728  NA        -31.2691
```